# Bones not flipping correctly on Symmetrize

Tags: rigging

I am following a tutorial to rig my character and I've correctly named all my bones but they aren't flipping correctly

Before Symmetrize:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tifzI.jpg

After Symmetrize(bones inside bones):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUoxg.jpg

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The symmetry will happen on X, so you need to rotate your armature 90° on Z in *Edit* mode before the symmetry